# Process data in a list

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to process some data that I've put in a list, but I'm not finding how to process them like a recursive tool.

I created the list containing the address of the .txt archives and I got this:

```
list_names
[1] "C:/Users/mrsir/Documents/IC/Dados Cinemetria/Am0001.txt"      
[2] "C:/Users/mrsir/Documents/IC/Dados Cinemetria/Am0002.txt"      
[3] "C:/Users/mrsir/Documents/IC/Dados Cinemetria/Am0003.txt"      
[4] "C:/Users/mrsir/Documents/IC/Dados Cinemetria/dados cinemetria.txt"
```

My code is based on take each of this data and take velocity, acceleration... using one column and making some vectors manipulation.

I take the data in this value "posicao", that receives one vector from that archives that I've talked above. I've already processed them separately, but all together I'm not finding the solution.

```
fc<-20
fs<-100
Wn<-fc/(2*fs)
butterw<- butter(5, Wn, type='low')
posicao<-data$column
```

Comment: Map a function though your list(or do a for  loop over elements of the list). Post some fake data and I can show you, you can add the import part later.

Comment: Olá Bruno, vi que é do Brasil, consigo comunicar melhor em português com você. Basicamente, meu código recebe o dado que contém pontos em vetores, daí de acordo com esse vetor posição eu crio demais vetores de velocidade, aceleração... Mas agora preciso processar vários dados de posição e criar esses vetores pra cada dado em tipo uma lista pra cada dado desses.

Comment: Oi Marcos, eu normalmente não falo aqui em portguês porque dá pra treinar o inglês kkk, mas eu preciso entender seu problema, eu não sei oq é butter(), se você postar mais detalhes do seu problema tem mais chances de eu conseguir te ajudar

Comment: Butter é um filtro. No caso preciso que naquele posição entre um arquivo de cada vez da lista lá de cima para processar e gerar os outros vetores que trabalho. Tipo um laço mesmo mas que seja com os arquivos da lista e que a cada laço gere vetores para cada arquivo. Deu pra entender +-?

Comment: Você só precisa desse dois vetores, butterw e Wn?